# How do I compress/minify component css at Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an Angular app which uses Universal SSR and I've noticed that HomeComponent which contains scss is not compressed when I have it uploaded and rendered on a node.js server.
The matter is that I have the scss compressed at my home.component.scss source file. Does Webpack do this? Not too sure.

So how do I have my component's scss file compressed while being rendered on a node.js server.

I've attached two images. One is the app's HomeCompnent scss source file, the other is a server-rendered rendered page.

[image: Compressed scss]

[image: SCSS not compressed at a rendered page]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to tell you. I just downloaded a seed ssr project from the GitHub and used is for my project. What exactly do you need to know, configuration of what?

Comment: Did you add  BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: <appid> }) ?

Comment: Yes, I have the "BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId:'angular-starter'})" in the app.module.ts imports array.

Comment: Are you sure your second image hasn't had a sourcemap applied to it?

Comment: MikeOne, to be honest I don't know it, Ima newbie. How do I check it?

Comment: MikeOne, you're quite right! There's the base46 decoded text below the uncompressed css. But...this means that a server is just rendering duplicated css or Webpack does this upon making a build, rigth?

Comment: As it turned out it's possible to turn off this mapping by adding the line below to the angular.json:         "server": {
          "options": {
            "sourceMap": false
          },